# How to combine different embedding's generated from different algorithms like from Word2vec, GLOVE , BERT?

Tags: stanford-nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I want to know about the best way to combine the different embeddings that I generated from different algorithms like word2vec, GLOVE, or BERT to generate the final one.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to combine vectors from multiple generation methods is to concatenate them. That is, if you have a 300-dimensional vector for the word `'apple'` from one method, and another 300-dimensional vector for that word from another method, concatenate the two into a 600-dimensional vector.

But, why do you want to this? Are you sure that would help? You should definitely test if such extra steps are worth the complication, in a small trials, before adopting it as a usual practice.

For example, Word2vec & Glove are very similar in what they model - you might find it simpler, and just as good or better, to spend more time tuning one method into a larger vector, than to try to mix-together.

Comment: basically, Word2vec  moving towards Doc2vec which is I am actually using to generate the embedding at the sentence level. So my goal is to find out the better embedding against each sentence from the above algorithms. For example  sent1: I love apples, Sent2: Apples are incredibly good for your health. so each of the algorithms generates its sentence-level embedding according to its nature. what I really want from these algorithms is to find out only the best embedding. Like for sent1 doc2vec produce the best embedding from all of the other algorithms.

Comment: Therefore I pick that embedding and for the sent2 glove give the best result and get that embedding. And finally, get the final best embedding matrix, that is further used for clustering purpose to group the same kind of sentence into particular clusters.